# Django wildcard query

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following logic in my application:

```
provider = request.POST.get('provider', '*')
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(provider=provider)
```

Is there a wildcard I can use in django, such that if no provider is found in the `POST` request, it will return all objects for it?

In other words, is there a way to accomplish this?

```
if request.POST.get('provider'):
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(provider=provider)
else:
    order_items = OrderItem.objects.all()
```

Comment: What's wrong with the version you show?

Comment: I have to do it ten times or so. It would just make things easier.

Comment: `"LIKE %something%"` is the SQL for wildcards ("%")  the percent sign is like "*"

Comment: I agree with @DanielRoseman the version you have shown seems like the right approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct wildcard parameter, so what you have is perfectly acceptable.  Code readability also counts, so even though you might end up with more code, it may be more maintainable.

You could chain the queryset like this:

```
provider = request.POST.get('provider')

order_items = OrderItem.objects.all()
if provider is not None:
    order_items = order_items.filter(provider=provider)
```

Or you could set up an empty dictionary of `kwargs` for a `filter()` call like this, but it's less readable in my opinion:

```
provider = request.POST.get('provider')
kwargs = {}
if provider is not None:
    kwargs['provider'] = provider

order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

This could be turned into a function call like this:

```
def all_or_filter_args(request, item):
    """Return dictionary of arguments for filter() if item is specified in request."""
    value = request.get(item)
    if value is None:
        return {}
    return { item : value }
```

and then the following one-liner used for queries:

```
order_items = OrderItem.objects.filter(**all_or_filter_args(request, 'provider'))
```

But again, I don't find this as readable as the example you've given.

Another approach is to write a [custom manager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) which allows you to use your own functions for filtering.   With a custom manager you could implement code to allow queries like this, where you provide a function for `all_or_filtered` to apply the correct filtering:

```
order_items = OrderItem.objects.all_or_filtered('provider', request.POST.get('provider'))
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this...

```
parameter = request.POST.get('provider', '%%')
order_items = OrderItem.objects.raw("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE provider LIKE '%s'" %   (OrderItem._meta.db_table, parameter))
```

Comment: It works in my PC very well.  Do you get any error or how it behaves?

Comment: I got no error. The output is `[]` empty. Wait I will try something